# NameError: name 'reload' is not defined python 3.6.4

Tags: python, django

After installing Xadmin, I encounter some problems. These are my error details:

```
[File "C:\Users\Harry\PycharmProjects\mxonline\lib\site-packages\xadmin\sites.py", line 9, in <module>
    reload(sys)
    NameError: name 'reload' is not defined][1]
```

I've tried to `import importlib importlib.reload(sys)` but it still doesn't work. I am using python 3.6.4.

Comment: Can you please provide some additional context? Or the code that you are encountering the error with? Does this happen when installing, when importing?

Comment: in additon to @BrandonBarney statement also add full traceback.

Comment: Oh geeze, `reload(sys)`? This code is doing something **really** weird.

Comment: Update your xadmin. This has been fixed for a year. (It is still really weird, though.)

Comment: Looks like the release on PyPI doesn't have the fix, though. You may have to use the Github version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is doing something super duper weird and incompatible with Python 3. Importing `reload` from `importlib` will not help, even if you were to edit the library's code to import `reload`, because it is also relying on `sys.setdefaultencoding`, which does not exist on Python 3.

To use this code on Python 3, you would have to install an updated version [directly from github](https://github.com/sshwsfc/xadmin), since the most recent release doesn't have the fix. I don't know whether the code has other issues with Python 3, though. Personally, I would probably not use xadmin at all.

Comment: to whom this may concern: this helped me in django1.11 (python2.7) to django3.1 (python3.6) migration

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that I understand the problem, you are having issues with importing `reload` from the package `importlib` and you encounter the `NameError` when trying to use `reload`.

If this is all correct, then make sure you are importing `reload` correctly. If you just want `reload` try:

```
from importlib import reload
```

This will import `reload` while making it available under the name `reload`. If you want to give it an alias you could do:

```
from importlib import reload as foo
```

Finally, if you needed all of importlib you could also import the package as an alias:

```
import importlib as il
```

And then use reload from this like so:

```
il.reload(sys)
```

Comment: i solved this problem by installing xadmin of github version